# SEO of a multilingual site, meta tags

Tags: seo

How do I implement the html document meta tags, so that a multilingual site gets indexed in the best way?

For instance, I have the following keywords in english, but I would like my site to get indexed in french and russian languages also?

```
 <meta name="keywords" content="furniture, interior design, interiors" />
 <meta name="description" content="furniture, interior design, interiors" />
```

I would like to add the same keywords translated in french and russian in the meta tags. 
For example:

```
 <meta name="keywords" content="furniture, interior design, interiors, meubles, décoration intérieure, intérieurs" />
 <meta name="description" content="furniture, interior design, interiors, meubles, décoration intérieure, intérieurs" />
```

Is this the correct solution?
What is the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking about this problem in the wrong way. Meta description tags aren't super important for SEO these days. Meta description tags have little effect on SERP placements. They CAN be used for descriptions for your site in SERPs, but you'd be better off with an overall content strategy.

Make sure the actual text on your site is translated correctly to French or Russian, depending on the location of the user. Find relevant sites frequented by users you want to visit your site and build links back.

Comment: No problem! Fresh, relevant content (as well as social media presence) will continue to increase in popularity and relevance for SEO going forward, and you'll be best served focusing on those areas.

Comment: "Make sure the actual text on your site is translated correctly to French or Russian, depending on the location of the user." > served under *different* urls